# Scripting a webcrawler to fill and send forms on remote sites

Tags: php, web-crawler

Now before you get out the torches and rail against spammers, I'll explain my intent here. I have written a series of scripts which scrape a certain website for contact information. These contacts are highly focused and are likely in a position where they are in need of a specific service I offer. The messages I plan on sending to them are one-offs and are written to be very helpful and respectful.

Now having said that, I'm having a hard time finding information on how to write a PHP bot that can enter a website, access a form, and send it. Everything I find is about *stopping* "spambots", unsurprisingly. I'm not worried about duping recaptchas or anything like that. If they have measures like that in place, I'm fine skipping them.

Comment: People WILL bring torches, yeah, not because of the crawler thing, but because of the fact that the question is way to broad!

Comment: how is this not spam? Just because you are self declared "good" spam, doesn't mean you're less spam for these people? You are cold calling their email.

Comment: @Martin Uh oh, Martin just pulled the tallest white hat from his closet and set it atop his dainty head.

Maybe read the posting guidelines, Martin. You're not going to find anything about voting down a post based on your personal morals. Well, except for maybe that you shouldn't do it.

Comment: sorry, but I did not vote down your question, @Brimby . I merely stated my view and requested clarity. I *did* _consider_ voting down but I felt I did not know enough to be sure that that was fair, and the question is not bad, but the reasoning behind it I feel is questionable and worth my comment. I know StackOverflow is frustrating in not knowing who votes up/down but I only vote down rarely and only when I know there has been a mistake or lack of effort.

Comment: for your info, @Brimby http://i59.tinypic.com/nbrz81.jpg

Answer (score 1):

This question is too broad, so I have to give you a broad answer too...

First you need to download the page. You can use cURL (or file_get_contents might sufice).

Then you need to parse it with an HTML parser. You can use DOMDocument that comes bundled with PHP but you'll probably choke since DOMDocument is not very forgiving about pages with HTML syntax errors (or HTML5, for that matter)

Then you need to traverse the DOM and look for the form itself, extract the url and the method and make a request.

You can then use cURL to send a submit request to that url.

However, this will fail for dynamic pages (for instance, angular and other heavy javascripted pages). You probably better to use a headless browser like phantomjs.

Comment: I already crawl and parse these websites and have located their forms. And I have encountered many AJAX forms and the like, so I will take your advice and check out phantomjs.